# How to send a tcl command to a tcl/tk interpreter from a C application

Tags: c, tcl, ipc, tk-toolkit

I am struggling with a problem and will appreciate your help.

Let's assume I have a tcl/tk application and interpreter 'x.y.123.3454' and I want to send some tcl procedures, which is defined in the 'x.y.123.3454', from a C application.

For example, I want to send `puts "Hello World"` from the C application to 'x.y.123.3454'. How to do it?

If you are wondering, why I am not running those procedures & commands directly in that tcl interpreter, please let me know.

Comment: If your TCL and C processes can be considered and dealt as independent processes, that any standard IPC mechanism may be used to transfer information between the two. The content, from the 'C' process is a text that can be 'eval-ed' from the TCL process upon receipt to execute the tcl command.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Whatever you have mentioned is desired but, how-to-do-it  is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the C level, a Tcl interpreter is represented by a handle of type `Tcl_Interp *` (which should be treated as if it points to an opaque structure). It's conventionally given the name `interp` by people working with the Tcl API, but that isn't really very important. Once you have such a handle, you use:

```c
int returnCode = Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts \"Hello World\"");
```

to run some code (the backslashes are there because we're putting double quotes inside a C string constant). The return code is going to be equal to `TCL_OK` if the execution finished successfully, and will equal `TCL_ERROR` if there was something that went wrong. In the OK case, you get the result value with `Tcl_GetObjResult(interp)` (and you can use `Tcl_GetString` on that to get the string version of the result for printing). In the error case, you use the same functions (i.e., `Tcl_GetObjResult`, `Tcl_GetString`) to retrieve the error message. There are other return codes possible, but you won't usually see them.

Of course, the result of `puts` is the empty string on success; the message is printed out, not returned.

---

How do you get that interpreter handle? Well, it really depends on how your code is integrating with Tcl. If you're writing a shared library that Tcl will `load`, it's the sole argument to your initialisation function. On the other hand, if you're embedding Tcl then you're probably calling `Tcl_CreateInterp()` at some point, which returns the handle to a newly-created interpreter. It's usually pretty obvious which you're doing.

Comment: I am aware of these two options. In C, it needs Tcl_CreateInterp() and in tcl, 'load'. But my question is slightly different, you already have a tcl interpreter with a specific appname (in my case,  'x.y.123.3454'). Now how do I call and send instructions (tcl commands) to this specific interpreter ?

Comment: I am quite hopeful that you will make it work. I seriously need your advice.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a good amount of time on this issue, I realized that there is no easy way to send a tcl command from C to an already existing tcl/tk application or interpreter.

Following link concurs:
http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/doc.html